# Spring MVC htmlspecialchars() alternative

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm looking for an alternative to PHP's htmlspecialchars() or even better, for a global solution using Spring MVC. For example, it would be great if data passed from Controller to View using ModelAndView or ModelMap was automatically processed so I could be sure that I'm working with safe strings inside jsp View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JSPs to display your data, all you need to do is use the JSTL's `<c:out>` tag, or `fn:escapeXml()` function to escame the HTML special chars:

```
Last Name : <c:out value="${someBean.lastName}"/>
First Name : ${fn:escapeXml(someBean.firstName)}
```

I would definitely not do this in the controller. This is one of the view's jobs.

Comment: Thank you. Well I didn't mean to to do this in the controller, I meant _between_ controller and view. For example interceptor's postHandle() method would do the job... go through all passed data and escape them automatically. But whatever, writing <c:out...> isn't such a big deal.